# When a point particle moves with a certain vector instantenous velocity along a curve, does it have a vector instanteneous acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

I'm sorry I'm just getting started with Physics, I'm not an expert. I've been stuck with this question.

When a point particle moves with a certain vector instantenous velocity along a curve, does it have a vector instanteneous acceleration? My professor said that it depends on the vector instanteneous acceleration. Though I don't understand why.

When I look at the graph I always see that the acceleration is the slope of the graph. Any hints?

Comment: I removed a couple of comments that were answering the question. Please keep in mind that comments are meant for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements, not for answering.

Comment: @DavidZ Thank you David. You should also tell the comment poster that you are deleting his comment so that he can take appropriate actions. This comment by the way is suggesting an improvement.

Comment: Can you post the graph you are talking about?  If not, can you describe what it is a graph of: position v. time, velocity v. time, something else?

Comment: If you don't understand what your teacher told you, the best person to ask for clarification is that teacher. We did not hear what your teacher said, so we do not know what he/she meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, a particle always has an acceleration (but this may be zero). Looking at a graph of *position* probably won't be very useful to gain an intuitive understanding of acceleration, but a graph of *velocity* will be.

First let's lay out the mathematics:

The time-dependent position of a particle in *n*-dimensions can be written as

$$\mathbf{x}(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1(t) \\ 
x_2(t) \\
\vdots \\
x_n(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The velocity and acceleration of the particle are simply defined as the derivatives of this vector with respect to time, i.e. 
$$\mathbf{v}(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf{x}(t) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1(t)}{\partial t} \\ 
\frac{\partial x_2(t)}{\partial t}  \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial x_2(t)}{\partial t} 
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf{a}(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf{v}(t)= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\mathbf{x}(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 x_1(t)}{\partial t^2} \\ 
\frac{\partial^2 x_2(t)}{\partial t^2}  \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial^2 x_2(t)}{\partial t^2} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in any (non-contrived) problem encountered in physics, **both of these will exist**. These are the definitions of velocity and acceleration, and as long as the derivatives are well-defined, these will exist.

The velocity is always tangent to the trajectory, and the acceleration is always tangent to the velocity. This does **not** imply that the acceleration is tangent to the trajectory.

Taking for example a 2D problem of a particle constrained to a circle, we see that the acceleration always points to the center of the circle, but the trajectory lies along the circle. Thus the acceleration is not tangent to the trajectory (but the velocity *is*!).

[image: Sorry the picture is so huge! Couldn't figure out how to make it smaller]

Comment: Thanks. Is the instanteneous acceleration always tangent to the trajectory?

Comment: @Cesare I will edit my answer to address your comment

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if a particle is changing direction it is accelerating. Example is a weight on a string that is being spun in a circle at a constant rate , there is a force (of the string) which is constantly accelerating the weight towards the centre and changing the weights direction of travel (velocity includes direction).

Answer (score 1):

When the particle moves along a "curve" and not a straight line then it does have an acceleration.

For a particle moving along a straight line, the magnitude of it's instantaneous velocity (or the speed) should change for it to have some acceleration.